# Jenkins + Make + xcodebuild or Jenkins + sh + xcodebuild

Tags: ios, xcode4, continuous-integration, jenkins

I saw [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ycxFcIPhQg) tutorial and I was wondering what were the advantages of using Make to setup targets for building and testing vs using sh scripts or event separate Jenkin jobs for build and test? I'm new to CI and scripting in general so sorry if this is kind of a silly question.

Answer (score 1):

You should choose the best language for your needs.  First start with what you know, if it is make files use them.  If your project already uses make files, then you should utilize them.

Other projects use different things, ruby has rake.

sh scripts are if you already have a working knowledge of them and need to run some tasks inside jenkins.  It could just as easily be a ruby or a php script.